# Unix find: multiple -o and exec not working together

Tags: bash, unix, find, osx-mavericks

When I run the following command, no files are moved despite the find command showing a result.

```
find "/Users/Vino/Media/test" -type f -size +100M \
  -name *.mkv -o -name *.mp4 -o -name *.avi \
  -exec mv {} /Users/Vino/Media/ \;
```

but when I remove the `or` operators for .avi and .mp4 it does what it is meant to

```
find "/Users/Vino/Media/test" -type f -size +100M \
  -name *.mkv -exec mv {} /Users/Vino/Media/ \;
```

It's a bit puzzling as it's a fairly simple command that I used to run under OS X 10.6. I'm now using OS X 10.9.

Comment: What if you change `-name *.mkv -o -name *.mp4 -o -name *.avi` to `\( -name *.mkv -o -name *.mp4 -o -name *.avi \)`?

Comment: Vino, Welcome to StackOverflow!  @Biffen If you post your comment as an answer, Vino can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

<sup><sup>Turning my comment into an answer.</sup></sup>

You'll have to make it clear for `find` which are the operands of `-o`. You can do that by grouping with `()`:

```bash
find "/Users/Vino/Media/test" -type f -size +100M \
  \( -name *.mkv -o -name *.mp4 -o -name *.avi \) \
  -exec mv {} /Users/Vino/Media/ \;
```

From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
( expr )
       Force precedence.  Since parentheses are special to  the  shell,
       you  will  normally need to quote them.  Many of the examples in
       this manual page use backslashes  for  this  purpose:  `\(...\)'
       instead of `(...)'.
```